# How to create an apex class to update a field for a specific record id?

Tags: apex, update

How do I create an apex class to update a field for a specific record id?

I want to then use this apex class to run based on a process builder

This works in open execute anonymous but not when i try to save as an apex class? any ideas?

```
Account XYZ = [Select Id, Flag from Account where ID = 'sdfsfsfdfdfdsf'];
XYZ.flag = 'No';
update XYZ;
```

Comment: Is there more to the class that you've tried to write? If so, would you mind including it all? If you're getting an error message, then including that too (the entire error message, including the stack trace) would be helpful. You can add details to your question by making an [edit]. If you're new to Apex, then the [apex quick-start project](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/quickstart-apex) on trailhead is probably where you should start.

Comment: Don't use a hardcoded ID. Instead, put it in a custom setting. Then you can set the value of the custom setting field in your test class to match an Account you insert.

Comment: HI, thank you for the response. All I want to do is to run the above update from a proces builder when a record is created.

So:

1. via process builder, when a Record gets created, exexcute apex class
2. the apex class then just updates the field value for a particular record

Answer (score 1):

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_action_apex.htm&type=5

You need to annotate the method with @InvocableMethod to call it from process builder. In the method, name a variable as a parameter and set this variable in the process builder based on whatever entered your criteria

```
public class UpdateAccountField
{
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void updateAccFlag(List<Id> accIds){
        List<Account> XYZ = [Select Id, Flag from Account where ID in: accIds];
        for(Account acc : XYZ){
            acc.flag = 'No';
        }
        update XYZ;
    } 
}
```

Comment: don't you want to be able to handle collections?

Comment: Definitely. Edited to do that.